# How to bind the JSON request body to a string primitive variable in Nancy?

Tags: c#, json, nancy

I have the following Nancy module.

```
public class MyFooTestModule : NancyModule
{
    public MyFooTestModule()
    {
        Post["/text"] = _ =>
        {
            //string myNewText = this.Bind<string>(); // Fails, because string has no parameterless constructor
            string myNewText = Request.Body.AsString();

            return Response.AsJson(myNewText);
        };
    }
}
```

where I want to bind to a single `string` variable. However, I cannot use `this.Bind<string>()` as I would for example use `this.Bind<int>()`, because during runtime I get an exception telling me:

```
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
```

If I use `Request.Body.AsString()` instead, the character escaping is not working properly and I end up with multiple quotes and escaped backslashes in my variable.

More precisely, when I post the JavaScript string

```
"Hello\r\nWorld Foo!"
```

from the client, I receive the echo JavaScript string

```
"\"Hello\\r\\nWorld Foo!\""
```

from the server.

What is the correct why to bind the JSON request body to a primitive `string` variable? I do not want to wrap every primitive type into an otherwise useless container class just to exchange `string` variables used in my JavaScript client.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely the result of a C# design decision, combined with a common practice for serialization within the framework.  The string type is immutable - an instance cannot be changed once created.  A common approach to serialization attempts to create an instance of the desired type and assign its member values. 
An alternative might be to pass the value as a parameter

```
Post["/text/{userString:string}"] = parameter => 
{ 
  // access the value herewith something like
  string theString = parameter.userString 
}
```

Off the top of my head, most other primitives will work, only string is immutable, though there are a several built-in types that won't work such as tuple and datetime.